# FileSystem Not supported error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using hadoop library **org.apache.hadoop.fs**. While trying to use **append()** method of class **FileSystem**, it is showing the error

```
    java.io.IOException: Not supported
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.append(ChecksumFileSystem.java:291)
```

I'm using the following statement,

```
fileSystem.append(path,getConf().getInt("io.file.buffer.size", 4096), null);
```

I configured everything properly.. Please help me find the cause/solution for this problem

Comment: which versoin of hadoop are you using?

Comment: What did you configured properly? Older version of hadoop don't support append - what's your version and target filesystem (HDFS, local, S3?)

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 0.20